# CSS class name changes for upgrade

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I am upgrading fullcalendar from v3 to v6. In the documentation for v4 to v5 it has been mentioned that a doc for css class name changes will be provided but i haven't found any till now. Is there something like that created?

a doc for css class name changes

Comment: That's something you would need to ask the fullCalendar team, if you can't find it published anywhere. Your best bet is probably to log it as a documentation feature request at https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues